# Is it possible to use query parameters to fill the IN keyword

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2005, ado.net

Imagine a table with GUIDs as primary key. I would like to select a few of these rows based on their primary key. I would like to use a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id IN ('firstguidhere','secondguidhere');
```

I am using ADO.NET to query the database, so I would like to use a parametrized query instead of dynamic sql, which would obviously work, but I want to retain the benefits of parametrized queries (security, escaping, etc...).

Is it possible to fill the collection for the IN-clause using sql-parameters?

Comment: There's a duplicate question here somewhere... finding it...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-a-sql-in-clause

Comment: @Jon, The accepted answer to that question isn't really optimal, although it's a hack that I've used many times myself, and would be fine for smaller tables and/or infrequent queries.

Comment: @jon, Thanks for pointing the other question out that out. I searched, but didn't find that question.
I consider using the second answer where you generate the parametrized query dynamically.
I consider this question closed. Can someone do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could pass the list of GUIDs as a comma-separated string parameter and use a table-valued UDF to split them into a table to use in your `IN` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM dbo.SplitCSVToTable(@MyCSVParam))
```

Erland Sommarskog has an [interesting article](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html) with examples of how to split comma-separated strings into tables using a UDF.

(For performance reasons, you should ensure that your UDF is inline table-valued, rather than multi-statement.)

Comment: Recently used the Sommarskog article to solve a similar problem.  Worked great for our needs.