# Adding a list of strings to OracleCommand.Parameters in C#

Tags: c#, oracle, ado.net

The following query has a parameter to be assigned with a list of strings:

```
select * from a_table where something in :list_of_strings
```

I have a C# `List<string>` which I would like to assign to the `list_of_strings` parameter.

Given an `OracleCommand` (representing the above query), how can I bind my `List<string>` to the command's `list_of_strings` parameter?

Comment: Not sure if this question is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6155146/problem-using-oracle-parameters-in-select-in or not.

Comment: This may help you. http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:139812348065

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, you can't bind a single parameter to a list of values. In this case you could concatenate the values to the query string.
However, that's unadvised since there's a limit of values you can put on an `IN` clause.

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("1");
list.Add("2");
list.Add("3");
list.Add("4");

string listStr = string.Join(",", list);
//result: "1,2,3,4"
```

If your string list is a list of strings, you could do this:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("one");
list.Add("two");
list.Add("three");
list.Add("four");

string listStr = string.Concat("'", string.Join("','", list), "'");
//result: "'one','two','three','four'"
```

Query string:

```
string query = string.Format("select * from a_table where something in({0})", listStr);
```

*Obs: you may have to handle the possibility where the list is empty.*

Another possibility would be inserting all the values on a temporary table and using it on the select statement. Which would have the advantage of unlimited string values and avoiding a new hard parse on the DBMS compared to the concatenating technique:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM A_TABLE 
   WHERE SOMETHING IN(SELECT SOMETHING FROM TEMP_TABLE)
```

Comment: Careful there.  If you are not sanitizing your list parameters, you open yourself up to a SQL injection.